# Caching yaml files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, yaml

My Rails application has a simple yaml file that's downloaded relatively frequently (5x per second). The file is updated very infrequently (at most once per day). I don't want to `YAML::load` the file every time it's requested. **What's the best way to cache this result?**

Comment: how did you end up avoiding the YAML::Load?

Comment: @RailsN00b sorry it's been too long to remember :-)

Comment: I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825970/is-it-efficient-to-load-a-yaml-file-as-a-constant-in-my-rails-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails provides an easy to using caching system:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('some_key', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
  ...
end
```

if the cache store doesn't contain some key then the block is evaluated and the result stored in the cache. There are several stores you can choose from, such as memcache, in memory, or the file system.